# Is "sit high" a set phrase?

Tags: phrases

Someone who is annoyed at the  coverage of her scandalous story in a news broadcasting tv programme (like bbc or cnn) is having a argument with director of the news network channel as to why she run the story.she says" it is sitting very high on her(the director) half hour".

Comment: Have you looked for the expression (or at least string) in a dictionary?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Yes, I have. it is not in the dictionaries.What is string?

Comment: I would say it's a "sit phrase".

Comment: A 'string' is any sequence of words found in a text, sentence .... It covers accidental juxtapositions as well as weak collocations / strong collocations ... / phrases / clauses .... //// ELU requires that basic research be done and presented (with links and attributions) where reasonably possible. Even "I found no evidence of 'sit high' in Lexico or AHD" is useful, showing where contributors may be better advised to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sit high" is a metaphor that derives from several sources.  In one sense it can simply refer to physical position ("The house sits high on a hill"), but it can also (presumably by analogy to a king's throne, etc) refer to one's social position or position of authority.

But in the referenced piece it sounds like "high" simply refers to the position of the piece in the broadcast schedule or list of priorities.

Answer (score 0):

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sit) has

*sit* = "to be in a particular position"

"The town sits at/in the bottom of a valley".

The verb is used in the same way to describe the position of items in an agenda. Those that sit high are those near the top of the agenda. Because a program has a similar list (schedule) of items to be considered during the broadcast, some items may be described as *sitting high* on the schedule (for "the half hour" of broadcast). The implication is sometimes that those items considered first in any such list (agenda or program schedule) are the most important.